# xp:repeat inside xe:dataView

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am currently having some trouble using a `xp:repeat` inside a `xe:dataView`.

**Scenario:** I'm using a `xe:dataview` which repeats some objects (same type) and shows them inside a form, but some of the objects contain more fields than others. So I have to create the fields and there valuebinding dynamic with an `xp:repeat`.

**My Problem:** I cant use the `var="rowvar"` of my dataView to calculate the value="" of my repeat control. But I need a reference on my obj inside the current row to calculate the fields.

Here a Simple Version of my Code(in my real scenario the obj is a Java Model Object):

```
<xe:dataView
    id="dataView1"
    var="rowvar"
    indexVar="objindex">
        <xe:this.value<![CDATA[#{javascript:[{fields:["field01","field02"]},{fields:["field01"]}]}]]></xe:this.value>
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:panel
            xp:key="summary">
            <xp:repeat
                value="#{javascript:do some stuff with rowvar}" or value="#{rowvar.fields}"
                var="field"
                indexVar="index"
                id="repeat1"
                repeatControls="true"
                rows="30">
                <xp:panel>
                    <xp:inputText
                        id="inputText1">
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[${javascript:
                                 var fieldName = "field0" + index;
                                 return '#{obj.' + fieldName + '}';}]]>
                        </xp:this.value>
                    </xp:inputText>
                </xp:panel>
            </xp:repeat>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:this.facets>
</xe:dataView>
```

As soon as I try to use the `rowvar` inside the `value="#{}"` of my repeat control I get a `[Reference] 'rowvar' not found` error. If I remove the `repeatControls="true"` I can't Access the index var inside my computed value binding any more... anyone got a solution on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not surprisingly, it's something Tim Tripcony has explained http://avatar.red-pill.mobi/tim/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-9CD3JN. The DataView, like a Panel, is "cleaning up" after itself. So when it restores the view after a partial refresh, it's removing all the requestScope pointers to the variable `rowvar`.

Because it's the value property of an editable control, it will be needed in ApplyRequestValues phase at the very earliest.

It may be possible to use Tony McGuckin's XSnippet http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=xrpl-isphase-api. That will allow you to identify the phases and compute the code at a phase after the requestScope variable has been set (so is not null), but before your code needs it. (**Caveat:** I've not tested to see whether the requestScope variable is set before it's needed.)

`repeatControls="true"` removes the repeat, so your code can no longer use rowvar.

**Update**

Now that I test the kind of thing you're trying, I realise it's failing *on page load* not *in partial refresh*. Again, it's a timing thing.

With `repeatControls="true"`, you are telling the XPage to load *x* rows in the "Page Load" event bound to the first *x* elements. So it will set `index`, the `indexVar` of the repeat, because it's iterating over the data to create *x* rows.

But the Data Table has (and can only have) dynamic binding. So during the "Page Load" event all the component tree is creating is a template for what to load into a given row. It hasn't looked at the underlying data for the Data Table. It will only iterate over that during the Render Response phase. So `rowvar`, the indexVar of the Data Table has not been set. There is no concept of a "row", there is just an abstract template for what will need to be loaded into each row during Render Response.

From a Java point of view, think of it like trying to get a value of a property from a Class (the template for each object created from that Class) rather than getting the value of the property from an *instance* of the Class.

The only way round that will be to change the Data Table to a Repeat Control and set `repeatControls="true"` on both the outer and inner repeat. Then everything will get built at Page Load, rather than the repeat at Page Load and the Data Table during Render Response.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the very nice explaination. I have to admit I never thought about using two repeat controls ;-) , in my opinion dataView & repeat where more or less the same (when used to repeat data)... both of them have the option `repeatControls=true`... time to read the documentation again. But with two repeat controls it works fine.